# 'package' must be of length 1 : HTML Widget error

Tags: r, rstudio, htmlwidgets

I am trying to create a html widget with flexdashboard elements in an object of class "shiny tag list". Expected output : An html file saved in my local drive.  Actual output

```
Error : Error in system.file(config, package = package) :    'package' must be of length 1
```

Here is a minimized version of the code:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

myflex1<- gauge(1.5, min = 0, max = 5, symbol = '', gaugeSectors(success = c(0, 2),warning = c(2,3.5 ),danger = c(3.5, 5)))

myflex<-   browsable(tagList
                     (list(tags$div(
                             style = 'position: absolute;
                             left: 100px;top: 350px;display:block',
                             myflex1
                           ))))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(myflex, "myflex.html")
```

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal reproducible example if you want any help with this.

Comment: I will add the code snippet here. Thank you.

Comment: That's not a reproducible example, and probably not minimal.  You need to post something that is self-contained and generates the problem you are seeing.  With that snippet, I get an error that the `browsable` function is not known.  I can guess you mean the one in `htmltools`, but then I get an error about a missing `fileSize`, because I don't have a file satisfying `file.path("***.jpg")`.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have added the whole portion of the code with the required amends. Basically, i am trying to create a dashboard using flexdashboard gauges and creating a shiny tag list to create a html file. While the object created so is browsable on R, I am unable to save it using htmlwidget. Thank you

Comment: You need to reduce your example to a *minimal* example that produces the problem.  I'm not going to do your debugging for you.

Comment: Hello, My apologies. I have edited the code to the minimal example format and saved it again. Could you please help with the error? Thank you.

Comment: `gauge` up there is missing its first argument.

Comment: Hey Dominic, I think it'd be a good idea to peruse this bad boy before asking a question. Pasting *just* code is almostworst thing you could do! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The edits I had saved did not populate accurately. I have re-edited my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` on something that is not a widget.  You should use `htmltools::save_html` instead; it knows how to write a Shiny tag list:

```
htmltools::save_html(myflex, "myflex.html")
```

Note that it will not create a self-contained page; it will write a list of Javascript libraries to a subdirectory (default name `"lib"`).  If you want something self-contained, you should be able to use this code:

```
cat(repr::repr_html(myflex), file = "myflex.html")
```

but I'm not sure that's what it's intended for, so you might find problems.

Comment: Hello, I agree save_html works for creating a file. However, that file is not selfcontained such that it can be sent to a different location as the html file's dashboard does not populate in that case. When I manually save the file from Viewer pane > Export > Save as web page the file runs well. However I dont know how to invoke the same via script. Could you help with that? Thank you

Comment: I've added an alternate solution.

Comment: That really helped a lot! Thank you so much!